# python3 sockets never stops trying to read data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, python-sockets

i'm using a tcp socket to read data from a website, HTTP requests to be exact. I want to use sockets and not requests or pycurl so please do not suggest me any higher level library.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = wrap_socket(s)
response_bytes = b""
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
s.connect((website))
s.send(all of this works good)
#this is where my problems occur
while True:
    response_bytes+=s.recv(4096)
    if not response_bytes: break
```

this solution should work perfectly according to multiple stack posts. I want to use the most efficient way without a timeout. If i use try/except and set a socket timeout it works fine but thats  not very good imo. This seems to make the code hang forever and make it try to read infinitely. Is there any reason it is doing this?

Comment: If you want to implement your own HTTP handling this is not adequate by a country mile. You need to read RFC 2616 and successors, particularly the parts a bit content length. I don't recommend it. Use a library.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> s.send(all of this works good)
> ```

Let me guess: this is doing a HTTP request with an explicit or implicit `Connection: keep-alive`. This header is implicit when doing a HTTP/1.1 request. Because of this the server decides to keep the TCP connection open because it is awaiting the next request of the client.

> I want to use the most efficient way without a timeout.

The correct way is to properly understand the HTTP protocol, extract the size of the response body from the response header and read exactly as much data as specified by the size. The easy way is to just do a HTTP/1.0 request without enabling HTTP keep-alive. In this case the server will close the TCP connection immediately after the response was sent.

> I want to use sockets and not requests or pycurl so please do not suggest me any higher level library.

It looks like you want to implement HTTP yourself. There is a standard you should read in this case which describes the fairly complex behavior of HTTP. Don't try to guess a protocol but read the actual specification.

Comment: so, instead of using 1.1 i should use 1.0 and remove the connection header and this method will work?

Comment: @coke: while I can only speculate what `all of this works good` actually is in your code a simple HTTP/1.0 request with no Connection header means that the server should close the connection immediately after the response is done in wich case `recv` will return with no more bytes read.

Comment: @coke Don’t substitute this excellent advice for having a good read of the documentation for the HTTP protocol

Comment: okay i see, so i need to keep the connection alive whenever possible so i believe i should keep my try/except and keep using 1.1

Comment: @coke: *"i believe i should keep my try/except ..."* - This is the wrong conclusion. The right conclusion would be to study the HTTP protocol so that you know exactly how many bytes you have to read.

Comment: im not trying to design a perfect system here, i do know how to do that, reading the content-length header given by the server before the data. I do have a good understanding of each header im using and its purpose.

Comment: i just need to make it as fast as possible hence why im not using requests.

Comment: @coke: *"i just need to make it as fast as possible"* - And that's why you should not run your own. The main performance problem is not in local computation but in network I/O. Running multiple requests over the same TCP connection and having content compression reduces this overhead significantly. Both of this is supported by requests but not by your code. While you are trading off simpler code against more complex code, you don't get faster code this way. Instead your code will run slower since it is not optimized to the problem. And no, it is not just the `content-length` header.

Comment: what content compression if you dont mind me asking? im requesting raw data using identity and not gzip compressed data, this is only for one site so i wont have to worry about servers only sending compressed data back, and also what else is it with the content-length header?

Comment: @coke: *"... im requesting raw data ..."* - right, you don't allow the server to optimize data for transport (i.e. compress) since you don't publish an appropriate `Accept-Encoding` header. Again, the main performance issue comes from network I/O and not the time the code is running. And less I/O due to compression means more performance. Also, TCP setup is costly too. *"...  what else is it with the content-length header ..."* - if you use HTTP/1.1 the server might reply with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and a chunked body and not `Content-length` with a body in one piece.

Answer (score 1):

> this solution should work perfectly according to multiple stack posts

No, you missed an important detail.

```py
while True:
    response_bytes+=s.recv(4096)
    if not response_bytes: break
```

If `response_bytes` is ever non-empty then it stays non-empty, and this becomes an infinite loop. Instead, do something like

```py
while True:
    buf = s.recv(2048)
    if not buf:
        break
    response_bytes+=buf
```